# Python 3.4 Multiprocessing Bug on Lock.acquire(), TypeError: Integer required

Tags: python, locking, multiprocessing, python-3.4, python-multiprocessing

Sometimes using a [multiprocessing pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) in combination with a manager and Python 3.4, `lock.acquire()` throws a strange `TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)`.

A few times this has come up on my Travis test suite and I am unable to figure out where it comes from and what it means. Even worse, I am unable to reproduce it reliably, it just happens or don't. Usually it doesn't but once every hundred runs or so it does :-(.

I am completely lost. Maybe someone has encountered something like this before and can give a hint on where to look for the bug's source. Let me start with the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pypet-0.1b10.dev0-py3.4.egg/pypet/environment.py", line 150, in _single_run
    traj._store_final(store_data=store_data)
  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pypet-0.1b10.dev0-py3.4.egg/pypet/trajectory.py", line 3271, in _store_final
    store_data=store_data)
  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pypet-0.1b10.dev0-py3.4.egg/pypet/storageservice.py", line 295, in store
    self.acquire_lock()
  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pypet-0.1b10.dev0-py3.4.egg/pypet/storageservice.py", line 284, in acquire_lock
    self._lock.acquire()
  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 958, in acquire
    return self._callmethod('acquire', args)
  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 731, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 413, in _send_bytes
    self._send(chunk)
  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 369, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
```

This only happens in python 3.4, but not 2.7 :-/.

My library producing the bug is rather comprehensive. However, basically what I do is the following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def my_job(object_with_lock):
    # do stuff in parallel
    returnvalue = 42  # has been computed in the parallel part

    object_with_lock.lock.acquire()
    # do stuff sequentially, file IO and so on
    object_with_lock.lock.release()
    return returnvalue


class MyClassWithLock(object):
    def __init__(self, lock):
        self.lock = lock


def main():
    manager = mp.Manager()
    lock = manager.Lock()
    my_object_with_lock = MyClassWithLock(lock)

    n_cores = 4
    pool = mp.Pool(n_cores)

    # Do the job concurrently:
    iterator = (my_object_with_lock for x in range(100))
    imap_results = pool.imap(my_job, iterator)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    del pool

    result_list = [x for x in imap_results]

    manager.shutdown()

    print(result_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code executes fine (although haven't tested it 1000 times), but it basically does what I do in the library.

How can something like this produce the error from above? Why does `lock.acquire()` throw this mysterious `TypeError` occasionally?

---

**EDIT:** Using Python 3.4.2 DOES replicate the bug (only in my library) but 3.4.1 does not o.O

Moreover, trying twice seems to overcome the problem, but that does not feel right:

```
try:
    object_with_lock.lock.acquire()
except TypeError:
    object_with_lock.lock.acquire()
```

---

**2nd EDIT:** After using `multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()` [thanks do dano] I can recover the following log messages. 
Somewhere it looses connection due to:

```
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-4] thread 'MainThread' has no more proxies so closing conn
```

But there's no error happening before, this jut comes out of the blue.

Moreover, directly before and after retrying to acquire the lock it says:

```
[Level 5/ForkPoolWorker-4] finalizer calling <function BaseProxy._decref at 0x7f5890307510> with args (Token(typeid='Lock', address='/tmp/pymp-huxl4h0k/listener-6mm0hc8b', id='7f58903128f0'), b'\x9aF7e\x02\xbc.\xb8\x87\xe0\x00?\xee\xf5\xd6J\x95@\x16\xb7s?\xbf\xe6\xa32a\x16\x13W(\xfb', None, <multiprocessing.util.ForkAwareLocal object at 0x7f58903621c8>, ProcessLocalSet(), <function Client at 0x7f5890375d90>) and kwargs {}
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-4] DECREF '7f58903128f0'
ERROR:pypet.retry:Starting the next try, because I could not execute `acquire_lock` due to: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-4] thread 'MainThread' does not own a connection
[DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-4] making connection to manager
[DEBUG/SyncManager-1] starting server thread to service 'ForkPoolWorker-4'
```

And apparently the connection is re-established. Still I don't understand why the connection was lost in the first place.

Comment: The error indicates sometimes the connection to the manager process is closed when you try to call `acquire` on the `Manager.Lock()`. It's hard to say why/how without a reproducible example.

Comment: But why does retrying work in such a case? Is the connection re-established?

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. You can add this at the beginning of your script to enable debug logging `multiprocessing`, which might help explain what's happening: `logger = mp.log_to_stderr() ; logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)`

Comment: Well, yeah In my library I use logging, so I see that retrying actually works and the program reaches the except block.

Comment: No, I mean the `multiprocessing` library itself has debug logging in it. If you turn it on, you'll see messages being logged by `multiprocessing` that might help explain what's happening internally.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?  Because I think I have the same problem, see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002812/multiprocessing-on-linux-works-with-spawn-only?noredirect=1#comment79107173_46002812 @SmCaterpillar